# Вывести только часть веб-страницы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$str=file_get_contents("http://www.heroeswm.ru/clan_info.php?id=41");
preg_match_all('/(Глава: .*?")/', $str, $name);
$name = implode("", $name[0]); 
echo $name;
```

Данный скрипт выводит со страницы всю инфу от "Глава" аж до "Протокол". Мне же нужно, чтобы вывело только ник Глава. То есть чтобы пропарсило от "Глава" и до конца ника самого Главы. Как исправить? Я так понял, что изменить требует только строку:

```
preg_match_all('/(Глава: .*?")/', $str, $name);
```

Comment: Заменил этим кодом, но ничего не появилось. Я так понял, он создает массив. Но как мне вывести это на страницу?

    if (preg_match_all('~<b>(Глава: </b><a class=pi href=\'pl_info.php\?id=\d+\'>(.*?))</a>~u', $str, $name)){
        print_r($name);
    }

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all('~<b>(Глава: </b><a class=pi href=\'pl_info.php?id=\d+\'>.*?)</a>~', $str, $name);
```

Да, моя ошибка. забыл "?" заэкранировать

вот новый вариант:

```
if (preg_match_all('~<b>(Глава: </b><a class=pi href=\'pl_info.php\?id=\d+\'>(.*?))</a>~u', $str, $name)){
    print_r($name);
}
```

выведет:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <b>Глава: </b><a class=pi href='pl_info.php?id=4598'>Игнациус</a>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Глава: </b><a class=pi href='pl_info.php?id=4598'>Игнациус
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Игнациус
        )

)
```

Comment: Не правильно. Ничего не выводит! 

Comment: после preg_match_all сделайте var_dump($name); что выводит?

Comment: обновил ответ